# How could I create a sub type of `I` that would wrap other sub types of `I`?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-2.10, generic-programming

Given the following in Java:

```
public interface Reply<T> {
  T data();
}

public class StatusReply implements Reply<String> {
  private final String status;

  public StatusReply(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  public String data() {
    return status;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do this in Scala:

```
class PassthroughReply[R <: Reply[_]](val reply: R)
  extends Reply[T] { // won't compile, `T` type not found

    override
    def data[T : Reply]: T = reply.data
}

val statusReply = new StatusReply("OK")
val passthroughReply = new PassthroughReply[SatusReply](statusReply)
passthroughReply.data // Should return "OK"
```

What I want is that the `data` in an instance of `PassthroughReply`, should have the same type as the `data` of its wrapped sub type of `Reply`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class PassthroughReply[T](val reply: Reply[T]) extends Reply[T] { 
    override def data = reply.data
}
```

Comment: If I do this, I would need to pass the type used by StatusReply e.g. `new PassthroughReply[String](new StatusReply("OK"))` I want it so that PassthroughReply can just infer the type used by StatusReply automatically.

Comment: The type of PassthroughReply can be inferred from the parameters you use to construct it. Try new PassthroughReply(new StatusReply("OK"))

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need to be able to type check with the type of `Reply`, e.g. `PassthroughReply[StatusReply]` instead of `PassthroughReply[String]`.